# Create a check that the device supports NFC and it is enabled - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, nfc, manifest

The condition which checks if the device supports NFC and it is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call system service to detect this,sample codes：

```
NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {
   //support NFC
}else{
   //doesn't support NFC
}
```

Comment: As per developer docs 

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#manifest



// Check for available NFC Adapter
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }